# Session variable Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

How do I store a session variable for a specific time?

Or how to reset a variable after a certain time?

I need to use `session.delete ('my_key')` 15 seconds after the event.

Comment: Set time in that session. if it valid means use it else remove it..

Comment: @VelusamyVenkatraman Time in session for variable, right? How can i do this?

Comment: Let's admit that you want to store a value and reuse it later with an expiration verification. You can store a hash in the session like this : `session[:my_key] = { value: 'whatever', time: Time.current }` then when you will want to check if it's valid you will be able to do something like `session.dig(:my_key, :time) > 15.seconds.ago ? what_you_want : session.delete(:my_key)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Rails will use `CookieStore` to store the session. This means all of sessions data will be stored in the cookie at the Client side. And, by this way, you can do sth like

```
session['your_key'] = 'Session Content'
session['your_key_expired_at'] = Time.current + 15.minutes
```

Then, later (for ex: `authenticate_user`), you can check

```
if session['your_key_expired_at'] < Time.current
   session.delete('your_key')
end
```

If you want the data still available after user closes the app, you can use `Cookies`, as below

```
cookies[:your_key] = {:value => "session stuff"}, :expires => 15.minutes.from_now}
```

You can use `signed cookies` to encrypt your cookies with the apps secret_token, as using `session`

```
cookies.signed[:login] = {:value => @user.id, :expires => 1.day.from_now}
```

Another option, in order to make it more secure, you can use `ActiveRecordStore` to manage and store session. You just pass the session id to your client, and you can easily manage your session at sever side because you know its `created_at`